# How do I change the original language in PHP files and Twig files?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have installed a Drupal 8.5 site in French (monolingual). Then, I added content.

Of course, there are many strings in the PHP files of my custom theme/module I pass to `t()`. There are also many strings in the Twig files I translated with `{{ 'a string'|trans }}`.

After a while, I added English.

Unfortunately, I discovered that all the strings (interface) I just mentioned are seen by Drupal as English string.

For example, using the [Translation template extractor](https://www.drupal.org/project/potx) module, I don't have the choice to extract the strings in English. I have only 2 options for the extraction: *Language independent template* and *Template file for French translations*.
When I use the [Translation Management Tool](https://www.drupal.org/project/tmgmt) module, all the locale sources strings have *Original language* under the English column and *Not translated* under the French column.

How do I tell Drupal that all my strings (PHP and Twig) are French strings?
Alternatively, what is the process to be able to export/translate in English, and import files (PO or XLIFF) into my site?

Comment: You add your string in the t() function like t('Bonjour')?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I tell Drupal that all my strings (PHP and Twig) are French strings?

You can not. There is no setting for that, the source code *must* be english.

Drupal *does* allow to translate the code/system-english to the actual english if you enable the checkbox when editing the english language. I don't know what that does exactly to potx and I don't think TMGMT supports it either.

Comment: Many thanks... but this is a really bad news! What would be the best process to translate my French site into English? You can link me to any resource.

Comment: As I said, the only thing that comes to mind is that you enable the checkbox on /admin/config/regional/language/edit/en, then you can manually translate it in the UI, but I don't know if/how you can export or use TMGMT.